# Inbound Email - Formatting? (emails with HTLM code are ignored)

Tags: civimail, email, activities

Can emails with HTML code (images, tables, etc.) be brought into CiviCRM with the inbound email job?  Any emails I have with images or tables get ignored by the Process Inbound Emails job.

In addition, can the inbound emails be formatted for better readability?  The email text is one long string in the "inbound email" activity detail.

Answer (score 1):

It's tricky to get html import right, both because the html we use in the web world and the one in emails is not quite the same (email html is stuck 10 years in the past)
... and because it's tricky to get it safe. being sure that an attacker doesn't use the email as a vector to inject javascript and other dangerous things is complex.

so going full html is probably not going to happen without significant investments, but you mentioned the issue of a single long line.

This one is probably easier to handle in a safe and satisfying way. Do you, or does someone in your team have some dev skills? it wouldn't be too hard to alter the display or the processing to inject 
 where they are new lines.

Comment: Xavier, thanks for the answer.  What you say about the HTML makes sense.  My group has limited Dev skills so I won't pursue that at this time.  My purpose for asking the questions was to determine if there was a standard or easy way to solve this before I try and roll out this functionality to a greater segment of our organization.  Thanks again.

Comment: Having line breaks in the inbound activity email would make my life WAY better, because otherwise this is one of the very best features of CiviCRM.